# PHP Eval on an object property

Tags: php, eval

Is it possible to simply this code...

```
echo $object->property1;
echo $object->property2;
echo $object->property3;
```

... with something like this, with eval ?

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
    echo eval("$object->property".$i);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why you didn't defined the property an as array from the first place?

Comment: The object is a drupal node, i can't !

Comment: WHY do you want to do this way? What's the purpose?

Comment: Why do you need eval() here, using eval() just to reduce 3 lines of code to 2 lines of code at a significant cost in readability, performance overhead and the risk of being eaten by a giant cockroach?

Comment: I simplified a lot here, but i've got a loooooooot of code to do for each property[number], and i'd like to put this code in a for loop, to avoid repetitions.

Comment: @Alarid - ok, look at Eduardo's suggestion. I think that is the best solution.

Comment: Indeed :) that's exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Accept his answer if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create the property name dynamically without using `eval()`:

```
$object = new stdClass();
$object->property1 = 10;
$object->property2 = 20;
$object->property3 = 30;

for ($i=1; $i<4; $i++)
    echo $object->{"property".$i};
```

Answer (score 0):

well $object would be out of scope in the eval function. you would need to define the object within the eval string.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this :

```
for ($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $tmp = "$object->property".$i
    echo $$tmp;
}
```

I'm not sure if dynamic variables are applied that way in OOPhP, I see the downvotes coming :-)